# How to create tag without asking a question?

Tags: support, tagging

I understand SE policy is that whenever someone asks a question with a new tag, the tag is automatically created. But is there a way to incorporate a tag without asking a needless question?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think ethnomathematics can be an useful, new tag, but I do not want to ask a question whose answer I can easily find using the tag.

Comment: Firstly, I disagree with this idea completely. Ethomathematics would be a great topic for a chat with friends, or a site about education. It would not make a good topic *here*. Secondly, if anyone would want to ask a question with this tag then the tag will be created. Until it is created there is no point in having it around.

Comment: Furthermore, unused tags are _automatically deleted_ at the end of every day....

Comment: @WillieWong I was looking at the [Unix.SE site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) and it read 60 days. Does it vary site to site?

Comment: I don't see the word `days` in that link you provided. On the other hand you should read the "When" section of that page.

Comment: Where do you see 60 days? Unused tags are deleted at the end of every day. Tags with only _one_ question to it are deleted after 6 months, which is about 180 days.

Comment: My mistake. 6 months, not 60 days.

Comment: Some details about how often empty tags and low-usage tags are deleted can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2829/). BTW this would be somewhat similar to feature-request in [Disambiguation pseudo-tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/disambiguation-pseudo-tags).

Comment: Maybe another way to create a tag is to add it to an existing question.

Comment: It is worth noting that MSE has one of the lowest (if not THE lowest) questions/tags ratio. This is not without reason, we work hard to reduce the number of tags. I feel that ethnomathematics tags will be unwelcomed and will it come to the meta site - I will vote against keeping such tag on this site.

Comment: I on the other hand will believe although the tag may welcome "soft questions" leading to arguments, such -for a lack of better word- jingoism will only fail to advertise the site. 

But before the nature of this question was derailed, my intention was to ask a general question on creating a tag regardless of content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to create a tag without attaching it to a question. It doesn't have to be a new question, but creating a tag in a vacuum isn't an option.

There's little point in having orphaned tags around and we already take steps to clean up tags without questions associated with them.